# How did @dave achieve his username?

Tags: discussion, display-names, unicode

[@dave](https://stackexchange.com/users/149341/dave)

[image: dave]

What's with those vertical characters? I don't know of any ASCII capable of producing that, but it must exist.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr50/

Comment: More annoying: http://stackoverflow.com/users/419/k̨̩̭͚̘̗̻̞͈͖̙͙e̗̦̼̳̣̦͜͡v̢̝̟̗̱̯͉

Comment: Great, now you caused whole bunch of users to do that...

Comment: @Arjan still better than the blank name some users have, making it impossible to click or reply in comments.

Comment: There is no ASCII capable of producing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**They're unicode's combining latin small letters.**

The combining bit is key here—combining unicode characters will 'combine' with the previous character, occupying the same or similar vertical space as the character prior to it that it combines with. Using multiple combining characters together will chain the combines together into a single character appending the previous properties to the next character, creating vertical text.

The actual text is equivalent to `dave evad` with the last four characters combining characters:

```
dave<space><combining-e><combining-v><combining-a><combining-d>
```

You can look up what unicode is used for a string by copying the string into [unicodelookup.com](http://unicodelookup.com):

[image]

Comment: That's also the secret of Zalgo.

Comment: what's the unicode for combining latin small letter f?... and u?

Comment: We @Won't tell you!